# R function not returning corpus

Tags: r, function, return, corpus

I have created a function to clean the corpus

```
#function to clean corpus
clean_corpus <- function(df, dfcol) {
  wordCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(data.table(df$dfcol)))                                                      #create corpus
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(stripWhitespace))                                       #remove whitespace
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))                                               #convert to lowercase
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeWords), c(stopwords('english'), 'john', 'james')) #remove stopwords 

  #replace foreign characters like "âë" to "'" to be removed in remove punctuation step
  removeForeignChar <- function(x) gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]","'" , x ,ignore.case = TRUE)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeForeignChar))

  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removePunctuation))    #remove punctuations
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeNumbers))        #remove numbers
  removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*",'',x)                      #function to remove URLs
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeURL))            #remove URLs

  return(wordCorpus)
}
```

Then I apply it to a dataframe called 'usvideos' and column 'title'

```
titleCorpus <- clean_corpus(usvideos, title)
```

However, when I check titleCorpus, I find that it is empty. How do I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Why are you using data.table around df$dfcol ? First line of your function.

Comment: Because it would raise an error when doing rowsums: error: cannot allocate size of 2.6gb. Converting it to data.frame somehow solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying df and dfcol to your function, just supply the column you need to analyze. The assignment of the column is not working correctly as df$dfcol is not recognizing the value you supply via dfcol. If you want this kind of behaviour to work, read up on lazy evaluation and the rlang package.

Also calling `data.table` inside the function is not needed. Use it outside the function if you need it, but not when you are returning a corpus.

```
#function to clean corpus
clean_corpus <- function(dfcol) {
  wordCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(dfcol))                                                      #create corpus
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(stripWhitespace))                                       #remove whitespace
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))                                               #convert to lowercase
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeWords), c(stopwords('english'), 'john', 'james')) #remove stopwords 

  #replace foreign characters like "âë" to "'" to be removed in remove punctuation step
  removeForeignChar <- function(x) gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]","'" , x ,ignore.case = TRUE)
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeForeignChar))

  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removePunctuation))    #remove punctuations
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeNumbers))        #remove numbers
  removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*",'',x)                      #function to remove URLs
  wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(removeURL))            #remove URLs

  return(wordCorpus)
}
```